# How to change image during game in spritekit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a character in the game (spritekit) and it is defined as:

```
 -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
       SKTexture* characterTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"firstappearancecharacter1"];
        characterTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
        SKTexture* characterTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"firstappearancecharacter2"];
        characterTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
        SKTexture* characterTexture3 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"firstappearancecharacter3"];
        characterTexture3.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

        SKAction* thataction = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[characterTexture1, characterTexture2,characterTexture3]timePerFrame:0.2]];
```

and I want to change the display of that character if an index:

```
NSInteger _myindex;
```

reach a certain value. Now, I want every time that index reaches some values like 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ...then the character will change his display, which is a new set of appearance images:

```
..textureWithImageNamed:@"2nd_appearance_character1"];
...
...textureWithImageNamed:@"2nd_appearance_character3"];
```

But where and how should I make it ?

Comment: When exactly is your `_myindex` incremented?

Comment: it will increase when the character hits certain objects in the scene

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way to do this, store all your textures in an array;

```
NSMutableArray* textureArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 1; i =< 3; i++) {
    //dynamically create an array of textures
    NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstappearancecharacter%d", i];
    SKTexture* tmp = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:string];
    tmp.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    [textureArray addObject:tmp];
}

SKAction* action = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:textureArray timePerFrame:0.2]];
```

Now for your question, first check if the increment index is even divisible by 5 if it is, dynamically get the texture from the array.

```
// to get the correct texture every 5 increments
if (self.myindex % 5 == 0) {
    int x = self.myindex/5.0;
    SKTexture* texture = [textureArray ObjectAtIndex:x];
}
```

---

**Pertaining your comment below:**

I would create an NSArray with all your different appearances and dynamically create the textures again.

```
NSArray* appearanceArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"firstappearancecharacter", @"secondappearancecharacter", @"thirdappearancecharacter", nil];
```

then incase the above for loop with another for loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < [appearanceArray count]; j++) {
     NSMutableArray* textureArray = [NSMutableArray array];

     for (int i = 1; i =< 3; i++) {
        //dynamically create an array of textures
        //then replace the NSString inside the above for loop with the below:
        NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", [appearanceArray objectAtIndex:j], i];
        SKTexture* tmp = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:string];
        tmp.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

        [textureArray addObject:tmp];
     }
}
```

Comment: It promises a very smart way for solve my problem! But here I can see a repeat of 3 image to create the action for only first set, it will be used in the TRUE of first condition. How about the second, third..set ("secondappearancecharacter%d","thirdappearancecharacter%d"..)? How do I input them and call from the Array?

Comment: Hey John, could you advise me on this so I could have a complete solution for my question ? Thanks !

Comment: I use this and got this error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, in the debug window, it shows : "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector". I guess the problem is because, normally I define: SKSpriteNode* _character;SKTexture* characterTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"firstappearancecharacter1"];     characterTexture1.filteringMode=SKTextureFilteringNearest;_character = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:characterTexture1];and from that I define the physicBody and all its _character.physicsBody; dynamic,BitMask, etc. from there. How now?

Comment: This is way passed the question you originally posted. I think you need to ask a new question because it's off topic. @user1314404 if my question has answered your original question please accept.

Comment: Dear John, actually I get some strange values when debugging with the above code. And I figure out it need 2 fixes: first. at the string line, it should be "i, j" instead of "i, i". second: I need to check the condition of index and at each condition set value for j, not put it in a loop, then put i loop inside that condition, also put action inside that. This is to avoid textureArray reset at each j loop. Now, the game can run, but I do not observe image change size during game. My suspicion is whether -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{ is the right place to put everything in?

Comment: to be simple I put the index is the score that increasing during game, but it looks like game does not come back and change the appearance up to the score. So it is not satisfy my question yet. Please advise, I think we are very close already !